# Use particle.js within ruby on rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to integrate that javascript plugin in my rails application. https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

**What I have done so far?**

```
application.js
  /* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */

     particlesJS.load('particles-js', '/particle.json', function() {
        console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
     });
```

I have put particles.js in vendor/assets/javascript and particle.json (config-file) in app/assets/javascript.
For some reason particle.son isn't loaded correctly.

**Error message:** 
Error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/particle.json")

**Edit** 
I tried to use the particles within a footer partial. That doesn't work.
Instead I moved the code to a regular page and that works. 
However I don't know why it works !?

Answer (score 1):

Is `particles.js` referenced in a manifest directive? For example, in application.js, ensure it is pointed to by `//= require particles` or `//= require tree .`

You are likely getting the routing error due to looking for the JSON object in your project's root `/` directory. Since you're using the Rails asset pipeline, change `/particle.json` to `assets/particle.json`:

```
     particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particle.json', function() {
        console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
     });
```